# Kalman Filter and OLS Results Are Different

Tags: regression, time-series, bayesian-network, kalman-filter

I read that Kalman Filters can be used for continuous / online linear regression and at the end of the regression its results and ordinary linear regression (OLS) results would be the same. I tried it on a sample time series data, using the model below for the KF (based on [this](http://www.mn.uio.no/math/tjenester/kunnskap/kompendier/komp_kalman.pdf) document),

$$ 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
\alpha_t \\ \beta_t
\end{array}\right] 
=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]  
\left[\begin{array}{r}
\alpha_{t-1} \\ \beta_{t-1}
\end{array}\right] 
+ 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\ 0
\end{array}\right] 
$$

$$ z_t = 
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & x_t
\end{array}\right] 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
\alpha_t \\ \beta_t
\end{array}\right] + v
$$

The code I have is

```
import numpy as np

def kalman_filter(x,y):
    delta=0.0001
    Ve=0.001

    yhat = np.ones(len(y))*np.nan
    e = np.ones(len(y))*np.nan
    Q = np.ones(len(y))*np.nan
    R = np.zeros((2,2))
    P = np.zeros((2,2))

    beta = np.matrix(np.zeros((2,len(y)))*np.nan)

    Vw=delta/(1-delta)*np.eye(2)

    beta[:, 0]=0.

    for t in range(len(y)):
        if (t > 0):
            beta[:, t]=beta[:, t-1]
            R=P+Vw

        yhat[t]=np.dot(x[t, :],beta[:, t])

        xt = np.matrix(x[t, :])
        Q[t] = np.dot(np.dot(xt,R),xt.T) + Ve

        e[t]=y[t]-yhat[t]

        K=np.dot(R,np.matrix(x[t, :]).T) / Q[t]

        beta[:, t]=beta[:, t]+np.dot(K,np.matrix(e[t]))

        P=R-np.dot(np.dot(K,xt),R)

    return beta
```

On sample data [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1570604/tmp/mcd.csv), ran it with

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mcd.csv',index_col=0)
y = df.MCD
x = np.ones((len(df),2))
x[:,0] = np.array(range(len(df.MCD)))
beta = kalman_filter(x,y)
```

The last values in the beta vector are 0.114 for slope and 7.538 for intercept. However, I ran an OLS on the same data

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
f = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
print f.params
```

I get

```
x1        0.049484
const    40.502940
```

This is completely different from KF results. The problem could be with the `x` vector, besides the intercept, I have `1,2,..,len(df)` in this variable, they are made-up but batch OLS is fine with this.

Then I thought my KF implementation might have been wrong, I tried it with the `pykalman` package - same results.

If I play around with the `x` vector (equally dividing `1,..,np.max(df.MCD)` and change scaling little bit) I can get close to OLS results. But from the explanations I saw on KFs, it seemed as if this would not be necessary. I am a little confused then why it is said that KF and OLS eventually give the same result.

Thanks,

Note: I contacted the author of the original version of the code above; he mentioned "KF will reach similar result as exponentially-weighted least square, not ordinary least square" - so latest data will be favored over earlier ones. More details [here](http://epchan.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/many-facets-of-linear-regression.html).

Comment: why don't you write the two minimization problems explicitely ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean - what are the two minimization problems? OLS works fine with same x,y - if KF is equivalent to OLS (at the end) then shouln't it report the same results?

Comment: you never saw a minimization problem ? see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation . the Kalman filter is the solution to some minimization problem http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-154-maneuvering-and-control-of-surface-and-underwater-vehicles-13-49-fall-2004/lecture-notes/lec20.pdf and your OLS is also a minimization problem. to understand why the two give (or not) the same result, you have to compare the two minimization problems

Comment: Ah - I thought you meant there were two minimization problems embedded in KF somehow. Well.. what I need is a direct answer, hopefully a numerical recipe on how to make KF work, on any time series.

Comment: no what you mean is understanding what you are doing, i.e. to what minimization problem the Kalman filter and your OLS are respectively the solution to. after that, implementation is straightforward.

Comment: That's the thing: I have the implementation; the one above comes from a time series analysis book, and it works when x and y both come from time series'. I bet there is a numerical trick to make it work for custom x i.e. (1,2,..,n) and any given y.